# Script Tag Type for Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to implement a script inside my HTML file. It's going to have jQuery inside, and I want to know what's the correct way of marking the script type attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">.......</script>
```

Right now it's implemented in this way, but it's showing me some errors. Or should I implement it like"text/jquery"? What's the correct way?

Comment: Remove `type` attribute from the the tag.

Comment: The errors are caused by the script itself, not because of the `type` attribute. Check your browser console. What error messages do you see?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript written by other people is still JavaScript. jQuery is not a programming language.

Omit the `type` attribute entirely for JavaScript (except when the file is an ES6 module).

You *can* use `type="text/javascript"`, but it is bloat and an opportunity to make a type that breaks things.

---

> it's showing me some errors

Whatever the errors are, they aren't caused by you using `type="text/javascript"` to load some JavaScript.